# How to query facebook graph api for comments using social plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website that implements the facebook comments social plugin on various pages.

Inside of facebook I can go to
`https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/<app id>`

and see all the comments that come in under this app.
I'd like to understand how I can query the graph api for these comments. It isn't immediately obvious from going through the graph API docs.

i think this is what i want
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/object/comments/
but i'm not sure what the object-id should be in this context

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1603507626630008

Comment: thanks, but i don't want it for a specific url, i all comments for any comment social plugin that uses this particular app id

Comment: I don’t think that is available via API directly.

Comment: hmm. is there a graph api that monitors notifications for a specific app?